# Set the number of numbers returned by my INDEX MATCH formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

To be simplistic, the formla below looks at different sheets in a workbook and for aany cells that matches the criteria it returns a number like:
001
002
003
And so on

```
=INDEX(Pack!A:A,MATCH(B2,TrackDataImport!H:H,0))
```

This all works as expected, however, with getting close to ten thousand unique cells I need it to return a number like:
00001
00002
00003

and so on.

This formula is not my own and I am unable to work out how to achive what I need?
It is probibly very obvious and I will feel foolish when it is revealed as such.

Comment: The formula will not do that, either change the values in `Pack!A:A` to what you want or if they are numbers, change the number format of the cell in which the formula is placed to include the extra `0`: `00000`

Comment: I guess you could do: =TEXT(INDEX(Pack!A:A,MATCH(B2,TrackDataImport!H:H,0)),"00000")` but that will only work if the values returned are numeric and not include any alpha characters.

Comment: Thank you. Both suggestions would work but your first suggestion is the answer. I said it would be something very obvious and I was right. i just didnt think of changing Pack!A:A.

Comment: Just so that you understand what that formula is doing: There is a one-to-one correlation between Pack!A:A and TrackDataImport!H:H, i.e. the value in ...H100 is associated with the value in ...A100. Your formula uses the value in B2 as a lookup value, matching B2 to the first occurrence of B2 in ...H:H (whole column H), and returns the row number where that match occurred. INDEX is now used to return the corresponding value at that matched row number in sheet Pack column A

Comment: Thanks Mobus, easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all your values are in Column A.

Step 1 : In Cell B1; enter the formula as B1= Text( A1, "00000")

Step 2 : Copy B1 down the column to get desired result.

Note 1 : Once it is converted in Text format, it can not be used as value.
So if you add column B, you get sum as 0. To utilise it again as value,convert it into value by a reverse formula ; C1 = Value(B1).... and copy down.

Thanks.